# Using a reactive array in a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to use a reactive array in a component. It works with an object but not with an array of objects.

How can I update the view when the array is updated?

```js
var self = currentClassInstance // this
 
self.store = {
    resources: Vue.reactive([]),
    test:  Vue.reactive({ test: 'my super test' }),

    setResources(resources) {
        // this one doesn't update the view. ?
        this.resources = resources

    }, 
    setResources(resources) {
        // this one update the view
        this.test.test = "test ok"
    },  
}


....

const app_draw = {
    data() {
        return {
            resources: self.store.resources,
            test: self.store.test,
        }
    },
       
    updated() {
        // triggered for "test" but not for "resources"
        console.log('updated')
    },
       
    template: '<div v-for="(resource, key) in resources" :data-key="key">{{resource.name}}</div>'
};
....
```

Comment: I'll try with Proxies... this.resources = resources erase Vue.reactive, it can't works

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [official docs](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/api.html#reactive) :

> **`Reactive`:**
> Takes an object and returns a reactive proxy of the original. This is equivalent to 2.x's `Vue.observable()`
> ....
> The reactive conversion is "deep": it affects all nested properties. In the ES2015 Proxy based implementation, the returned proxy is **not** equal to the original object. It is recommended to work exclusively with the reactive proxy and avoid relying on the original object.

i suggest to assign the array to field called value inside the reactive parameter like you did with `test` :

```
resources: Vue.reactive({value:[]}),
```

then use `resources.value=someVal` to update that value.

Answer (score 4):

A quick way

```js
const resources = reactive([]);

// set resources
resources.length = 0;
resources.push(...items)
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the answers above, there are two main ways to handle reactive arrays

Single array with mutating values

```
const arr = reactive([])
arr.length = 0  // clear
arr.push(...items)
```

Changing array reference to immutable values

```
const arr = ref([]) // equivalent to reactive({value:[]})
arr.value = ["Shiver", "me", "timbers"]
```

Both will trigger reactive updates

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

- `resources: Vue.reactive({value:[]})` can be avoided by making the whole store reactive
- `data()` is a local copy, but you really want a single source of the truth (i.e the store), so access it via a computed property (basically the way Vuex works).

```
var self = currentClassInstance // this

self.store = Vue.reactive({
  resources: [],
  setResources(resources) {
    this.resources = resources
  }, 
})

const app_draw = {

  computed: {
    resources() {
      return self.store.resources
    }
  }
       
  template: '<div v-for="(resource, key) in resources" :data-key="key">{{resource.name}}</div>'
};
```