# Vuex - Error 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')' when using Vue.set()

Tags: arrays, vue.js, object, set, vuex

I am getting the following error in console when trying to use Vue.set():
[image]

Am I missing imports? I am trying to update an array of objects - please can someone help?

Thanks

```
import { VueElement } from 'vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  state: {
    activeLightScenes: [
      {'room': null, 'scene': null},
      {'room': null, 'scene': null},
      {'room': null, 'scene': null},
      {'room': null, 'scene': null},
    ]
  },
  mutations: {
    updateLightScenes(state, room, scene){

      Vue.set(state.activeLightScenes, 'room', room, 'scene', scene)
    },
  },

  getters:{


  },

  actions: {

  },

  modules: {

  },

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely have Vue 3 installed, and `vue@3` has no default export, so `Vue` would be `undefined`, leading to the error you observed with `Vue.set`. However, in Vue 3, you don't need to use something like `Vue.set`. The equivalent code would just be setting the variable directly.

Assuming you also pass an array index of the element in `state.activeLightScenes[]` that is to contain the specified `room` and `scene` arguments:

```js
export default  createStore({
  ⋮
  mutations: {
    updateLightScenes(state, room, scene, index) {
      // Vue.set(state.activeLightScenes, 'room', room, 'scene', scene) ❌ remove this
      state.activeLightScenes[index].room = room
      state.activeLightScenes[index].scene = scene
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me, I have an array of objects just like the op and it's not reactive.  Any ideas? In my situation I have to modify the entire array not just singular values because it's getting a JSON response back.  How can this work if you don't pass the array index?

Comment: In vue2 there was the issue that for object which are created during runtime the reactivity wasn't setup. So it might be similar to vue3, that the reactivity has to be set for a new object in the array?

Comment: Well in vue3 it should be needed anymore:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64416979/2733509